# Converting Ruby time to objective-c

Tags: objective-c, ruby, nsdateformatter

2015-02-11T12:54:18.050-06:00

I'm confused about the .050-6:00 formatting. Is the last -6 from GMT? What's .050? How do I show this in a date formatter?

I'm just trying to get the Month, Day, Year and want to do it properly with date formatting instead of string parsing..

Comment: 18.050 is seconds, isn't it?  And the -6 is from GMT.

Answer (score 0):

0.50 is the microseconds.  Check out Ruby's `strptime` command.

```
> Time.strptime('2015-02-11T12:54:18.050-06:00', '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%L%:z')
=> 2015-02-11 12:54:18 -0600
```